# Virtual Assistant - Python

Tags: python

So I just started programming on **python** and I'm making my own virtual assistant, I have a problem where **I want "Eve" to say a phrase before I talk**, but I does not work. I know is something stupid but I just started recently so I'm stuck with this problem, hope someone help me with this.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def greeting():
    engine.say("Hello I'm Eve. How can help you?")


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'Eve' in command:
                command = command.replace('Eve', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command


def run_eve():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        talk('Current time is ' + time)
    elif 'who is this' in command:
        person = command.replace('who is this', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
        print(info)
        talk(info)
    else:
        talk('Please say the command again.')


while True:
    run_eve()
```

Comment: Please specify the text you want 'eve' to say, reading code consumes a lot of time

Comment: "Hello I'm Eve. How can help you?" That's the one

Answer (score 1):

It's not running because you hav'nt called the function `greeting`. So just add `greeting()` in `run_eve` function.

If you want to run `greeting` only once throught out the program, there are 2 ways:

1. Changing the function:

```
def run_eve():
    Greeting()
    while True:
        command = take_command()
        print(command)
        if 'play' in command:
            song = command.replace('play', '')
            talk('playing ' + song)
            pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
        elif 'time' in command:
            time = 
             datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
            talk('Current time is ' + time)
        elif 'who is this' in command:
              person = command.replace('who is this', '')
              info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
              print(info)
              talk(info)
        else:
             talk('Please say the command again.')
```

Just all the code you want to repeat in a loop, and the code you don't want to repeat: keep it out side the loop.

2. Changing while loop

```
Index=0
while True:
    If index==0:
         Greeting()
         Run_eve()
         Index+=1
    Else:
         Run_eve()
Just use a variable to check how many time loop is running, if it's 0 then run the greeting otherwise just run the Main function.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't call `greeting()`. Maybe:

```
def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'Eve' in command:
                command = command.replace('Eve', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        command = False  # Change this line
    return command


def run_eve():
    command = take_command()
    if not command:  # add this and two line below
        greeting()
        return
    print(command)
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        talk('Current time is ' + time)
    elif 'who is this' in command:
        person = command.replace('who is this', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
        print(info)
        talk(info)
    else:
        talk('Please say the command again.')
```